# python: logging:: get the current time in a custom timezone

Tags: python, logging

I am trying the following code to log using the timezone 'America/New_York'

the time is shown correct, but the %z and %Z are not showing the right time Zone

```
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone
import logging

def timetz(*args):
    tz = timezone('America/New_York')
    print(tz)
    dt = datetime.now(tz)
    print(dt)
    return dt.timetuple()



logger = logging.getLogger()


formatter = logging.Formatter(fmt='%(asctime)s::%(levelname)-8s\n%(message)s',datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %p %Z %z')
formatter.converter = timetz
formatter.default_msec_format = '%s.%03d'

handler= logging.StreamHandler()
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logger.addHandler(handler)
logger.error('test')
```

I get

```
2021-03-05 14:53:04 PM UTC +0000::ERROR   
test
```

But i should get

```
2021-03-05 14:53:04 PM EST -0500::ERROR   
test
```

The %z and %Z are not working